# Tell if device driver timeout has occured with wait_event_interruptible_timeout

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Within my device driver, I am using `wait_event_interruptible_timeout`. How can I tell if a timeout has occurred? The macro only returns errorcode on interrupts but timeout is not an interrupt so "0" is returned.

---

Edit: not sure on how to tell if timeout occurred, but `condition` wont be set, so that sounds like the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same confusing issue a couple of weeks ago after reading the description of that function in [Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/). Upon reading the comments for the various wait functions in a current kernel source tree, however, I found that the API has changed since the book was published. Newer kernels (at least 2.6.34+ and  probably quite a bit further back than that), return the remaining number of jiffies to the timeout instead of an error code. So, a zero return value indicates the timeout occurred and any non-zero value should indicate a successful wakeup via the event condition. The comments in `include/linux/wait.h` provide a good description of the new API.